# Area of CPTBarPlot field?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-plot

When using a `CPTScatterPlot` I can call `plotAreaPointOfVisiblePointAtIndex` which gives me a `NSPoint` of where the specific index is on the graph.

I've been trying to figure out if I can do something similar to get the area (x,y,width and height) for a datapoint of my `CPTBarPlot`, but so far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Does anyone know of any was I can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ErikSkroch's details, this is the solution I came up with (a little bit hacky as I ended using the private methods rather than re-writing the math).

```
// Access to private methods
@interface CPTBarPlot()
-(CGFloat)lengthInView:(NSDecimal)decimalLength;
-(BOOL)barAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx basePoint:(CGPoint *)basePoint tipPoint:(CGPoint *)tipPoint;
@end

 NSPoint basePoint, tipPoint;
 if(![barPlot barAtRecordIndex: index
                     basePoint: &basePoint
                      tipPoint: &tipPoint]) return;

 float width = [barPlot lengthInView: barPlot.barWidth];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the data index, you can get the location, base, and tip values from the datasource (or the model data it uses). Adjust the bar location with the `barOffset` if you're using it. Use the plot space to convert from data coordinates to plot area pixel coordinates for the ends of the bars. If `barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates` is `YES`, you can use the `barWidth` as the pixel width of the bar rectangles. If it is `NO`, you'll need to do some math to offset the corners of the bars before converting to plot area coordinates. You can look at the [`CPTBarPlot` implementation](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTBarPlot.m#L762) if you need help with the calculations.